# Crashed application doesn't show any error window

Tags: windows, exception, desktop-application

I have simple windows form application that does following

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        throw new Exception();
        //...
    }
```

When I ran `.exe` file I've expected to see a window like this

[image]

but it doesn't show up, and it only shows loading cursor for a while. Why?

Comment: Are you sure the Main function is actually called? Did you try to step through it and see if the Exception is thrown?

Comment: It throws fine in debug mode and VS catches it.